# Creating tables in PHP with an integer name using a for loop

Tags: php

I am trying to make multiple tables in SQL with PHP and these tables need to be named by numbers between 1920 and 2017.  I am using a for loop, however being new at PHP, my code is does not seem to work.  there is no error being given back and it is not echoing back anything as well.  What am I doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("---", "---", "---", "---");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

for($i = 1920; i<=2017; $i++)
{
    $sql="CREATE TABLE `".$i."` (site_coordinator VARCHAR(66),aanouncements VARCHAR(1000),description VARCHAR(1000)";

    // Execute query
    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
        echo "Table ";
        echo $table;
        echo "created successfully";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
      }
} 

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You sure want to create that **97** tables ?

Comment: You do *not* want to create all those tables, believe me.

Comment: Seems not to be a well proofed architecture

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but I decided, after Shakar's comment it would be smarter just to create a single table with multiple columns.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Also that missing $ was a typo in typing into the message, that was not in my original code... sorry about that too

Comment: Yeah make a table something like this: `CREATE TABLE newTable ( year int(4), site_coordinator VARCHAR(66), announcements VARCHAR(1000), description VARCHAR(1000) )`

When you want to get all the rows for, say, year 2004, you would do this: `SELECT * FROM newTable WHERE Year = 2004`

Answer (score 1):

This line is not  correct

```
for($i = 1920; i<=2017; $i++)
```

Should be as

```
for($i = 1920; $i<=2017; $i++)
```

You are missing the $

Answer (score 0):

Even if I think there is a design misconception if you need to create all thoses tables, there is few errors in your code

missing $ in for, useless quotes in the query and missing parenthesis in the end of the query.

Here is the correct code:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("---", "---", "---", "---");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

for($i = 1920; $i<=2017; $i++)
{
    $sql="CREATE TABLE ".$i." (site_coordinator VARCHAR(66),aanouncements VARCHAR(1000),description VARCHAR(1000))";

    // Execute query
    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
        echo "Table ";
        echo $table;
        echo "created successfully";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
      }
} 

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

To debug easily, print your query with something like `echo $sql`, then do the query by hand, you will see the errors in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

As this has already been said, you don't want to create all these tables. Really, you don't.
Put instead an additional `Year` field and make your application group, or sort, or whatever by year. Thus you'll need only one single table with flexible sorting and grouping abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much better approach to what you're trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE years
(
    year int(4),
    site_coordinator VARCHAR(66),
    announcements VARCHAR(1000),
    description VARCHAR(1000)
)
```

When you want to insert data for, say, year 2004, instead of doing this, as with your original design:

`INSERT INT0 2004 (site_coordinator, announcements, description) VALUES ...`

you would be using a single table **using the year column**, like this:

`INSERT INTO years (year, site_coordinator, announcements, description) VALUES (2004, "xxx", "xxx", "xxx") ...`

When you want to get all the rows for a specific year, you would do this:

`SELECT * FROM years WHERE year = 2004`

And so, the resulting PHP code would be as simple as this:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("---", "---", "---", "---");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="CREATE TABLE `years` (year INT(4), site_coordinator VARCHAR(66), announcements VARCHAR(1000), description VARCHAR(1000) )";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "Table years created successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Note there was a misspelling correction to the column `announcements`